# JFrame paint does not overriding

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

to execute flow chart Symbols.
But JFrame paint method is not working for this method.

```
package floating;
import designs.*;   //mydesings for executing flow chart Symbols
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
    boolean START,PASS;   //for using
    int SPEED=1;

    JSlider jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
    JSeparator js=new JSeparator();
    JToggleButton jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton("START");
    JToggleButton jToggleButton2 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton("PASS");

    Test(String a)
    {
        JFrame jf=new JFrame(a);
        Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jf.setSize(dim.width,dim.height-30);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        jToggleButton1.setLocation((dim.width/2)+30,25);
        jToggleButton1.setSize(100,30);
        jToggleButton1.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton2.setLocation((dim.width/2)+50+100,25);
        jToggleButton2.setSize(100,30);
        jToggleButton2.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton2ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        js.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        js.setForeground(Color.red);
        js.setLocation(dim.width/2,0);
        js.setPreferredSize(dim);
        js.setSize(10,dim.height);
        jf.add(js);

        jSlider1.setLocation(dim.width-300,20);
        jSlider1.setSize(250,50);
        jSlider1.setToolTipText("Set to Seconds");
        jSlider1.setMinimum(1);jSlider1.setMaximum(5);jSlider1.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        jSlider1.setMinorTickSpacing(1);jSlider1.setValue(1);
        jSlider1.setPaintLabels(true);
        jSlider1.setPaintTicks(true);
        jSlider1.setPaintTrack(true);
        jSlider1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jSlider1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jf.add(jSlider1);  
        jf.add(jToggleButton1);
        jf.add(jToggleButton2);

        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void jToggleButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) 
    {
        if(jToggleButton1.getActionCommand()=="START")
        {
            System.out.printf(jToggleButton1.getText());
            jToggleButton1.setText("STOP");
            this.START=true;
            System.out.println(this.START);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf(jToggleButton1.getText());
            jToggleButton1.setText("START");
            this.START=false;
            System.out.println(this.START);
        }
    }
    public void jToggleButton2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) 
    {
        if( jToggleButton2.getActionCommand()=="PASS")
        {
            System.out.printf(jToggleButton2.getText());
            jToggleButton2.setText("RESUME");
            this.PASS=true;
            System.out.println("   "+this.PASS);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf(jToggleButton2.getText());
            jToggleButton2.setText("PASS");
            this.PASS=false;
            System.out.println( "  " +this.PASS);
        }
    }
    private void jSlider1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
    {

       this.SPEED=jSlider1.getValue();
       System.out.println(SPEED);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) //testing paint method
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawLine(10, 20, 50, 70);
        repaint();
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test a=new Test("Test");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please Help to fix this question.

Comment: Did you accidently delete the beginning of your question?

Comment: Try using JPanel instead of JFrame to paint and override `paintComponent` in the JPanel class after you create it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test class extends JFrame. So if you want to have overridden paint method to work, you have to create an object of Test class. And make it setVisible(true)

In stead, you are creating another JFrame object in Test's constructor. Don't create it. The object of Test itself is a JFrame. Add all components to Test object in stead of JFrame object (jF).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't invoke repaint() from a painting method. This will cause an infinite loop.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples. Start with the example from the tutorial and make changes so your class is better designed.

Don't use "==" for string comparisons. Use the `equals(...)` method.

Also, in the future, post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you ask a question. Your question is about painting so most of the code you posted is unrelated to the question.

Comment: Calling `repaint()` from `paintComponent()` does not technically cause an infinite loop. `repaint()` returns immediately after queuing a repaint request. Your program will continue to run pretty much normally, since those requests are being generated periodically anyway.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, is causes an infinite loop because the paintComponent() method is continually executed. Add a System.out.println(...) to the paintComponent() method. Run the code without a repaint() and then run it again with the repaint to see what output you get. Also try monitoring the CPU usage. On my machine it goes from 0 to 25% which again is an indication of an infinite loop.